# error: cannot move out of borrowed content for self field

Tags: rust

Here is my code:

```
struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(data : T) -> Node<T> {
        Node { data: data, next: None } 
    }
    fn new_with_next(data: T, next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>) -> Node<T> {
        Node { data: data, next: next }
    }
}


struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Box<Node<T>>,
    size: u8,
}

impl<T> LinkedList<T> {
    fn new(data: T) -> LinkedList<T> {
        let new_node = Node::new(data);
        let head = Box::new(new_node);
        LinkedList { head: head, size: 1 }
    }
    fn insert(&mut self, data: T) {
        let mut next = Some(self.head);    // <-- error here
        let new_node = Node::new_with_next(data, next);
        self.head = Box::new(new_node);
        self.size += 1;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
src\linked_list.rs:28:29: 28:33 error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
src\linked_list.rs:28         let next = Some(self.head);
                                              ^~~~
```

I don't understand the error, nor how to fix it. I tried giving a reference to `self.head` to `Some`, however I'm changing the data type this inside `Some` this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you take `self` by reference, therefore you cannot move out its `head` (it would become invalid), which `let mut next = Some(self.head);` would do.

[`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) is a nice function for this:

```
fn insert(&mut self, data: T) {
    let mut next = std::mem::replace(&mut self.head, Box::new(Node::new(data)));
    self.head.next = Some(next);
    self.size += 1;
}
```

It allows you to replace the head with a new node and get the old one *at the same time*, which Rust is happy about because `head` stays valid all along now.